# Do Star Trek questions belong here?

Tags: discussion

I have noticed that there is a Star Trek stack exchange site in proposal. On other sites in the Stack Exchange network, when a question is asked which would belong on a site in proposal, it is generally closed, the asker referred to the site and urged to commit to it.

I wholeheartedly agree with this policy, as I find that it encourage people to migrate the sites with which they can offer the most expert advice to the community.

Should questions related to Star Trek be closed? I believe they should, UNLESS they are a comparison with some other science fiction work.

Comment: Why the downvoting? Do people think this is a bad question, or are they trying to indicate disagreement?

Comment: @neilfein: It has long been established that on the meta sites, down-voting is simply a way to indicate "no" or "I do not agree with your suggestion." It is not meant to say that it is necessarily a *bad* question. We removed reputation earnings from meta specifically to allow people to vote freely without introducing the emotional element of being down-voted.

Comment: @robert perhaps the "please add a comment" popup on down voting is inappropriate on meta then?

Comment: The correct question should be: Why do we need a Star Trek SE site proposal, if we have **this** site? :>

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No, Star Trek questions should *not* be closed.

Sometime very soon, proposals that are entirely on topic here — and Star Trek *is* on topic here — will be closed. They will be closed as a duplicate of *this* site and the followers will be asked to bring their support here.

Questions are closed when they are off topic for the site. Off-topic users will be directed to support a proposal if it will give them a home for their question. But a legitimate topic is not made off topic on a site because there is another *proposal* on that subject.

Comment: Quite a definitive response! I admit to being somewhat taken aback, having had a place setting question on the cooking site closed because there was an etiquette site in proposal. Despite any snark you may detect from me, I am actually as pleased with this answer as anyone. As long as I know the rules, I will happily follow them!

Comment: There are still a lot of questions on the main sites for which would otherwise be more aligned with a more specific SE forum. Questions can always be moved at a later time.

Answer (score 15):

I actually take a different view, that the Star Trek proposal should be closed and subsumed by this group. One of the neat things about Stack Exchange is the ability to tag questions, so that if a person only wants to be involved with Star Trek, they can do it.

Answer (score 12):

I think that if/when this site looks like it's going to have a successful beta period, it'll be time to close that Area 51 proposal (along with other, similar, proposals).

Right now, it's too early to say (imo).

But banning ST-related questions from this site because they *might*, someday, have a site of their own isn't a viable option.

Comment: This is a defensible approach, but for consistency with other sites in the SE network, I still stand by my position.

Answer (score 2):

There are already sites that overlap. Programmers just came out of beta, and we have questions that could be appropriate on both sites. This is a non-issue. Star Trek is science fiction, and therefore on-topic. If the new site comes out of Area 51 (and to me, it seems too narrow a focus, but who knows?) then questions can be migrated there. But it doesn't exist now, and I see no reason to close them just because a more specific site *might* come out.

Comment: +1 for migration. It's like *ex post facto* for questions.